# How to Specify Intended Variable When two Variables Have Same Name and Different Scope in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, scope

Let's say in Dart (DartPad) we have:

```
String a = "I am higher in the scope chain";

void main() {
  String a = "I am lower in the scope chain, but I have the same name";
  print(a);
}
```

Is there a keyword we can use so that it prints the variable in the parent scope instead such as:

```
print(parent.a)
```

or

```
print(this.a)
```

?

(Those don't work).

Comment: I don't believe there is, except for a few limited things with "this".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you filename is 'some_dart_file.dart', you can do this

```dart
import './some_dart_file.dart' as parent show a;

String a = "I am higher in the scope chain";

void main() {
  String a = "I am lower in the scope chain, but I have the same name";
  print(parent.a);
}
```

Comment: You can use an empty string to refer to same file in import as well, for example `import '' as parent;`